# SQL Server : restore database without exclusive access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore

We are trying to restore a live database (call it `db_name`) to a temporary database (call it `db_name_tmp`) from a full backup on a SQL Server 2014 instance.

We are getting the famous error:

> Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use

After looking around I am unable to find a way to restore this database *without* taking the database **offline** or setting it to `single_user`.

Is there a way to restore a database without requiring exclusive access to the current database?

### Edit #1:

Below are the SSMS screenshots
[image]

[image]

Comment: No, as far as I know, there is not - restoring a database **absolutely requires** exclusive access - you cannot restore a database while other users are still working on it .....

Comment: @marc_s thanks! what if I the server crashes and I needed to restore to another server? How is that any different than restoring to another database on the same server?

Comment: NOTE: It *only* requires exclusive access on the RESTORE *target*.  It should not require exclusive access on the source DB.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in one step?  Is it possible your actions are trying to restore the real db "db_name" instead of the db_name_tmp.

Comment: @SqlSurfer, when using the SMSS GUI I did rename the table on the `Destination` section. Maybe something in the `Options` I'm not configuring right? adding screenshots in a few minutes

Comment: @RBarryYoung could it be I'm leaving the option `Take tail-log backup before restore` on?